# UV Texture Offset Animation on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation, xna, xna-4.0

Without custom shaders (WP7), how is a simple UV texture animation possible? I just need it to offset like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=VbDjHMer0Bw#t=309s

Can I do this on a Model or even just a bunch of vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible without custom shaders if you change the vertices being drawn.

If you have a vertex array somewhere, you can do the following in `Update`:

```
var speed = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f);
Vector2 uvOffset = speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; ++i)
{
    vertices[i].TextureCoordinate += uvOffset;
}
```

Since the vertices are changing so often, it is a good idea to draw them directly using `DrawUserPrimitives` or `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`, e.g.:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
```

On an XNA `Model` everything is stored in non-dynamic `VertexBuffer`s, which means your only choice is to copy the buffer, change it, and recopy it back in. **Beware** that this is potentially very slow and memory-hogging, depending on how complex your model is. So keep this in mind.

```
var speed = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f);
Vector2 uvOffset = speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

//unset first
GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(null);

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    foreach (ModelMeshPart mp in mesh.MeshParts)
    {                    
        //copy array first to change it
        var newVertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[mp.VertexBuffer.VertexCount];
        mp.VertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(newVertices);

        //offset all texture coords
        for (int i = 0; i < newVertices.Length; ++i)
        {
            newVertices[i].TextureCoordinate += uvOffset;
        }

        //set data back into buffer
        mp.VertexBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(newVertices);
    }
}
```

If you capture the initial texture coords in an array, you can always go back to them after a certain amount; that way you're not restricted to constantly wrapping the entire texture.